# Why I can't add this object into this list?

Tags: c#

I am absolutly new in **C#** and I have the following problem trying to insert an object into a Collection.

So I have a base class named **VulnSmall** that contains some properties, then I have a class named **Vuln** that **extends** the previous **VulnSmall** class adding to it some properties including a list named VulnerabilityReferences, as you can see in the following code snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataModel.Vulnerability
{
    public class Vuln : VulnSmall
    {
        .......................
        .......................
        .......................
        public virtual List<VulnerabilityReference> VulnerabilityReferences { get; set; }    

        .......................
        .......................
        .......................

    }
}
```

Ok,

in another class I have something like it:

```
DataModel.Vulnerability.Vuln currentNVDVuln = new DataModel.Vulnerability.Vuln();

// Creation of the VulnerabilityReference object and initialization of its fields:
DataModel.Vulnerability.VulnerabilityReference currentVulnRef = new DataModel.Vulnerability.VulnerabilityReference();

currentVulnRef.Title = "My Title";
currentVulnRef.Description = "My Descripion"
currentVulnRef.URL = "www.myurl.com"

// Adding the previous obkect to the VulnerabilityReferences list field:
currentNVDVuln.VulnerabilityReferences.Add(currentVulnRef);
```

As you can see I have a **Vuln** object named currentNVDVuln (that contains the **VulnerabilityReferences** list as its field), I create a **VulnerabilityReference** object (named **currentVulnRef**) and I try to add it to this list.

But don't work and when try to execute this line:

```
currentNVDVuln.VulnerabilityReferences.Add(currentVulnRef);
```

it go into error and throw this **Exception**:

> {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
>   System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}

Why? What could be the problem? What am I missing?

Comment: what about a debugger? have you tried to debug the exception

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: By the way, why is that property `virtual`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not initializing `VulnerabilityReferences` list. Thus it has `null` value and it throws exception when you try to call its `Add` method. You can create new list in constructor of `Vuln` class:

```
public class Vuln : VulnSmall
{
    public Vuln()
    {
        VulnerabilityReferences = new List<VulnerabilityReference>();
    }

    // ...
}
```

From C# Specification [10.4.4 Field initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645756%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (with auto-implemented property you still have field, but its generated by compiler for you):

> The initial value of a field, whether it be a static field or an
>   instance field, is the default value (Section 5.2) of the field's
>   type.

List is a reference type, so by default it will have value `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize `VulnerabilityReferences` , it would better if you do it in your constructor:

```
public class Vuln : VulnSmall
{
    public Vuln()
    {
       VulnerabilityReferences = new List<VulnerabilityReference>();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In constructor of the `Vuln`class you need to do this:

```
public Vuln()
{
   VulnerabilityReferences  = new List<VulnerabilityReference>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add something to a list that does not yet exist.

It isn't enough to define your list property, you must also initialize it. For example:

```
public class Vuln : VulnSmall
{
    public virtual List<VulnerabilityReference> VulnerabilityReferences { get; set; } 

    public Vuln()
    {
        this.VulnerabilityReferences = new List<VulnerabilityReference>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You get a null reference exception because the reference to the list is null. You only have a reference for a list, you have to create the actual list at some point:

```
VulnerabilityReferences = new List<VulnerabilityReference>();
```

You can do that for example in the constructor of the class:

```
public class Vuln : VulnSmall {

  public virtual List<VulnerabilityReference> VulnerabilityReferences { get; set; }    

  public Vuln(){
    VulnerabilityReferences = new List<VulnerabilityReference>();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should *create* a `List<VulnerabilityReference>` to insert item into:

```
...

currentNVDVuln.VulnerabilityReferences = new List<VulnerabilityReference> VulnerabilityReferences();

currentNVDVuln.VulnerabilityReferences.Add(currentVulnRef);
```

But a better solution is to *redesign* `VulnSmall`

```
  public class Vuln : VulnSmall {
    // List is created on Vuln creation
    private List<VulnerabilityReference> m_VulnerabilityReferences =
      new List<VulnerabilityReference>();

    // You're not going to set a whole list, are you?
    // That's why no "set" here
    public IList<VulnerabilityReference> VulnerabilityReferences {
      get {
        return m_VulnerabilityReferences; 
      }
    }
  }
```